# Problem with Margin on a Loader (Desktop version)

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-animations, margin

I have a problem with a loader on my home page, I have to use a tablet look for the desktop version, with space on the left and right of the website.
So i used, margin : 0 auto 0 auto for the body on desktop.
The problem is my loader is also following this rule, it's not in the center anymore, I've tried to give it a margin : 0 but doesn't work, I've also tried to give a negative margin, it's moving but it's not really responsive..
If you have any solution, I would appreciate !
I'll provide some pictures so you can understand easier : [image: Loader][image: After the loader]

```css
.chargement {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: loading;
    animation-duration: 2.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.chargement_bloc {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.chargement_bloc-cercle {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 20px solid #fff;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    animation-name: circle;
    animation-duration: 2.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    visibility: hidden;
}
@keyframes circle {
    0% {
        visibility: visible;
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    99% {
        visibility: visible;
        transform: rotate(1500deg);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: -1;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
@keyframes loading {
    0% {
        background-color: #9356DC;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    99% {
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #9356DC;
    }
    100% {
        z-index: -1;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}


html {
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 993px) {
    body {
        width: 993px;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        background-color: #5D5D5D;
}
}
```

```html
<body>
<!-- Barre de chargement -->
    <div class="chargement">
        <div class="chargement_bloc">
            <div class="chargement_bloc-cercle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin is there because on your `media-queries` you are using `min-width` So essentially your media-queries are being implemented in your desktop version, which is not what you want. Hence, it is using the `width: 993px;` you set to it.

I changed `min-width` to `max-width` assuming you want the media styles to happen **BELOW 993px**. `max-width: 993px` **= anything below 993px**. So now, between 0-993px screen width, your media queries will take effect. Alternatively, `min-width: 993px` means anything **ABOVE** the **set range**, in this case 993px.

```css
.chargement {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: loading;
    animation-duration: 2.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-position: center;
}
.chargement_bloc {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.chargement_bloc-cercle {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 20px solid #fff;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    animation-name: circle;
    animation-duration: 2.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    visibility: hidden;
}
@keyframes circle {
    0% {
        visibility: visible;
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    99% {
        visibility: visible;
        transform: rotate(1500deg);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: -1;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
@keyframes loading {
    0% {
        background-color: #9356DC;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    99% {
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #9356DC;
    }
    100% {
        z-index: -1;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}


body {
    margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 993px) {
    body {
        width: 993px;
        margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        background-color: #5D5D5D;
    }
    
    .chargement {
      width: 993px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
<!-- Barre de chargement -->
    <div class="chargement">
        <div class="chargement_bloc">
            <div class="chargement_bloc-cercle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```